# Can we use dummy variables to capture the nonlinearity in Age, Period, and Cohort effects?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, constrained-regression

According to the chapter[Bayesian Age-Period-Cohort Models](https://books.google.com.hk/books?hl=zh-TW&lr=&id=ohcHEAAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA142&dq=Bayesian%20Age-Period-Cohort%20Models%20E%20Fosse&ots=XmetNpmGfj&sig=chx9_gkcEuQgMwriTo4ooonJpBY&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Bayesian%20Age-Period-Cohort%20Models%20E%20Fosse&f=false) written by Ethan Fosse, the Classical APC Regression Model is the method I referred to in the question. In my specific case, I opt to set the period effects for the years 2000 and 2005 as equal, imposing constraints during model estimation. The rationale behind selecting these two periods lies in my assumption that their effects are highly similar. Here’s how the implementation will proceed:

```r
set.seed(123)
period_test = rep(seq(2000, 2020, 5), 3)
age_test = c(seq(30, 50, 5), seq(50, 70, 5), seq(70, 90, 5))
cohort_test = period_test-age_test
period_test = period_test %>% fastDummies::dummy_cols() %>% modify(as.factor)
period_test$period_2000_2005 = period_test$period_2000 + period_test$period_2005
period_test$period_2000=NULL
period_test$period_2005=NULL
names(period_test) = names(period_test) %>% gsub('.data_','period_',.)
death_data = c(rpois(5, 30), rpois(5, 20), rpois(5, 20))

testing = data.frame(period_test, age_test, cohort_test, death_data)
tt = glm(death_data ~ period_2000_2005 +
         period_2010 + period_2015 + period_2020 +
         as.factor(age_test) + as.factor(cohort_test),
         family = poisson, data = testing)
```

The result is as below:

```r
Call:  glm(formula = death_data ~ period_2000_2005 + period_2010 + 
    period_2015 + period_2020 + as.factor(age_test) + 
    as.factor(cohort_test), family = poisson, data = testing)

Coefficients:
               (Intercept)            period_2000_2005                 period_2010  
                   3.66537                    -0.29808                    -0.52988  
               period_2015                 period_2020       as.factor(age_test)35  
                  -0.52988                          NA                    -0.14842  
     as.factor(age_test)40       as.factor(age_test)45       as.factor(age_test)50  
                   0.04256                     0.19671                    -0.48732  
     as.factor(age_test)55       as.factor(age_test)60       as.factor(age_test)65  
                  -0.37609                    -0.44967                    -0.44967  
     as.factor(age_test)70       as.factor(age_test)75       as.factor(age_test)80  
                  -0.72824                    -0.18924                          NA  
     as.factor(age_test)85       as.factor(age_test)90  as.factor(cohort_test)1950  
                        NA                    -0.52988                    -0.04676  
as.factor(cohort_test)1970  
                        NA  

Degrees of Freedom: 14 Total (i.e. Null);  0 Residual
Null Deviance:      16.68 
Residual Deviance: -1.554e-14   AIC: 103.1
```

There is still NA in the result, which indicates that the model has more parameters than can be estimated from the data. So we may need to impose more constraints on the variables.

One more thing to note is that, since Age, Period, and Cohort effects are in the same model, they are highly nonlinear (Mason, Mason, et al. 1973: 246). I have another new question: *Can we use dummy variables to capture the nonlinearity in Age, Period, and Cohort effects?*

You may check the chapter written by Ethan Fosse, or the Summer Institutes in Biostatistics of the University of Washington (by Jon Wakefield):

[Module 3: Age-Period-Cohort Modeling and Analysis](https://si.biostat.washington.edu/suminst/archives/SISCER2021)

[Lecture 1: Preliminaries](https://faculty.washington.edu/jonno/APCmaterial/SISCER-APC-2021-Lecture1.pdf)

[Lecture 2: Identification and Modeling](https://faculty.washington.edu/jonno/APCmaterial/SISCER-APC-2021-Lecture2.pdf)

[Lecture 3: Splines, Smoothing, Bayes and
INLA](https://faculty.washington.edu/jonno/APCmaterial/SISCER-APC-2021-Lecture3.pdf)

[Lecture 4: Bayesian Methods](https://faculty.washington.edu/jonno/APCmaterial/SISCER-APC-2021-Lecture4.pdf)

The link to previous question:
[Poisson regression with constraint on the coefficients of two variables be the same](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/602309/poisson-regression-with-constraint-on-the-coefficients-of-two-variables-be-the-s?noredirect=1#comment1198087_602309)